# Different types of DataTypes in Realm(Android Application) DataBase?

Tags: android, database, realm, realm-mobile-platform, android-database

Which datatype are use in realm database(i.e. String,int etc.)?
What is the size of that DataType?

> (i.e. in mySQL varchar max length is ***65,535***.)

Comment: See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#field-types and also https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#limitations-general

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks , now i am clear with the dataTypes of realm but still confused with dataType size. is this size depends on **realmObject** which we extends our model file?

Answer (score 6):

Realm supports **boolean**, **byte**, **short**, **int**, **long**, **float**, **double**, **String**, **Date** and **byte[]** field types.

Also specific types of `RealmModel`, and `RealmList<T>` where T is a supported field type of Realm.

Size limitation of String , byte[] is 16MB.

Comment: Thanks @Suhan Ts , i m understand  with data types which you explain but what about the size of dataType?

Comment: All the datatypes occupy their primitive sizes in realm but **String** and **byte[]** have a limited size of 16 mb.